# python - create new column based on last two letters of a string

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a large dataframe containing many thousand URNs each with a country code on the end. I would like to create a new column that isolates those country codes:

my df:

```
    urn
0   CS16-1533232-GB 
1   CS16-1533233-GB     
2   CS16-1533234-GB 
3   CS16-1533235-BZ 
4   CS16-1533238-GB
```

Desired output:

```
    urn              country
0   CS16-1533232-GB   GB
1   CS16-1533233-GB   GB
2   CS16-1533234-GB   GB
3   CS16-1533235-BZ   BZ
4   CS16-1533238-GB   GB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always have 2 letters, simply slice:

```
df['country'] = df['urn'].str[-2:]
```

Else, extract the last letters with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['country'] = df['urn'].str.extract(r'([A-Z]+)$', expand=False)
# or non "-"
df['country'] = df['urn'].str.extract(r'([^-]+)$', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
               urn country
0  CS16-1533232-GB      GB
1  CS16-1533233-GB      GB
2  CS16-1533234-GB      GB
3  CS16-1533235-BZ      BZ
4  CS16-1533238-GB      GB
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the characters after the final hyphen, you could do as follows:

```
df['country'] = df['urn'].str.split('-').str.get(-1)
```

Output:

```
    urn country
0   CS16-1533232-GB GB
1   CS16-1533233-GB GB
2   CS16-1533234-GB GB
3   CS16-1533235-BZ BZ
4   CS16-1533238-GB GB
```